# Local indexes vs Global indexes for partitioned tables in Oracle

Tags: oracle, database-partitioning

I have partitioned a table that is growing almost at a rate of 7-8 million rows a day. The partitioning has been done using a timestamp column as data can be archived or discarded a few weeks later. I have also created an index on the table which are on primary key or another value that is unique. My indexes are partitioned as well, however the partioning of index has been done using a hash function and does not include the partition key of table (which is a timestamp). So I have a few questions.

The table is a write-intensive table. It is currently mostly inserts, one update per row and 2-3 lookups within seconds of creation by indexed id and then the record is never accessed for any operation.

- Is it optimal to define local indexes on the unique id or is it better to define global indexes and partition them as I have already done? If I define global indexes, without table partitioning key in it (timestamp, which is not used in lookup), will the access be more expensive if the number of partitions is huge?
- What are the downsides of having global partitioned indexes for constantly growing data?
- Once I decide to remove the partitions at a later point of time, since the indexes are not partitioned by timestamp but instead by unique id, will the operation cause a direct impact on functioning indexes?

Any other recommendations will be helpful.

Comment: I think you would have a better and specialized attention at http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: A general solution without drawbacks would be to embed date bits into id field and solely use it for partitioning and quering.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I don't know any reason to make an index partition different to table partition (that's what you have).

Either make global index or local index, i.e. partitioned index where partition of index is the same as partition of underlying table.

When you have global index and you drop or truncate a partition then the global indexes becomes "unusable" and have to be rebuild. You can automatically achieve this by adding clause `UPDATE INDEXES` to your drop/truncate statement. However, such operation may take some time, this is the main drawback of a global index.

In general local indexes are better, they are easier to maintain and usually faster since they are smaller. However, if you have many partitions and your main queries do not include the partition key (the timestamp in your case) then local index may have a negative impact on performance. If you have let's say 100 partitions, then Oracle would have to scan 100 index partitions which basically means: Scanning 100 indexes! In such case a global index is much faster.

Comment: Thanks. This is in line with my understand and also the reason why I created global index partitions different from table partitions. We query records by id. And my intial thinking was that if I am querying by id and the records are growing massivly, then it is beneficial to split indexes than table. The performance gain for subsequent insert and update was visible but wasn't a lot. So I experimented with partitioning tables, assuming that maybe growing table size also makes subsequent inserts and updates slower. Due to archival needs, I need to split data by date. But for update query by id.